# Resizing images with Nodejs and Imagemagick

Tags: node.js, mongodb, imagemagick

Using nodejs and imagemagick am able to re-size an image and send it to the browser with this.

```
    var http = require('http'),
        spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

    http.createServer(function(req, res) {

        var image = 'test.jpg';
        var convert = spawn('convert', [image, '-resize', '100x100', '-']);

        convert.stdout.pipe(res);
        convert.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

    }).listen(8080);
```

The test image is read from the file-system, I want to alter so that test image is a binary string.

```
var image = 'some long binray string representing an image.......';
```

My plan is to store the binary strings in Mongodb and read them of dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using `spawn()` to invoke the ImageMagick command line `convert`, the normal approach is to write intermediate files to a temp directory where they will get cleaned up either immediately after use or as a scheduled/cron job.

If you want to avoid writing the file to convert, one option to try is base64 encoding your images and using the [inline format](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#inline).  This is similar to how images are encoded in some HTML emails or web pages.

```
 inline:{base64_file|data:base64_data}
 Inline images let you read an image defined in a special base64 encoding.
```

**NOTE:** There is a limit on the size of command-line options you can pass .. Imagemagick docs suggest 5000 bytes.  Base64-encoded strings are larger than the original (Wikipedia suggests  a rough guide of [137% larger](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#MIME)) which could be very limiting unless you're showing thumbnails.

Another ImageMagick format option is [ephemeral](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#ephemeral):

```
 ephemeral:{image_file}
 Read and then Delete this image file.
```

If you want to avoid the I/O passing altogether, you would need a Node.js module that directly integrates a low-level library like ImageMagick or GD rather than wrapping command line tools.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at the node module [node-imagemagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick/). There is the following example on the module's page to resize and image and write it to a file...

```
var fs = require('fs');
im.resize({
  srcData: fs.readFileSync('kittens.jpg', 'binary'),
  width:   256
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  if (err) throw err
  fs.writeFileSync('kittens-resized.jpg', stdout, 'binary');
  console.log('resized kittens.jpg to fit within 256x256px')
});
```

You can alter this code to do the following...

```
var mime = require('mime')   // Get mime type based on file extension. use "npm install mime"
  , fs = require('fs')
  , util = require('util')
  , http = require('http')
  , im = require('imagemagick');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    var filePath = 'test.jpg';

    fs.stat(filePath, function (err, stat) {
        if (err) { throw err; }

        fs.readFile(filePath, 'binary', function (err, data) {
            if (err) { throw err; }

            im.resize({
                srcData: data,
                width: 256
            }, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                if (err) { throw err; }

                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': mime.lookup(filePath),
                    'Content-Length': stat.size
                });

                var readStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

                return util.pump(readStream, res);
            });
        });
    });
}).listen(8080);
```

Ps. Haven't run the code above yet. Will try do it shortly, but it should give you an idea of how to asynchronously resize and stream a file.

Comment: Thanks or you answer. But this is not what want to do. I never want read anything from the file-system.

Answer (score 0):

What have you tried so far? You can use GridFS to store the image data and retrieve as a stream from there.. This in C#..Not sure if this helps..

```
public static void UploadPhoto(string name)
{
    var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var database = server.GetDatabase("MyDB");
    string fileName = name;
    using (var fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open))
    {
        var gridFsInfo = database.GridFS.Upload(fs, fileName);
        var fileId = gridFsInfo.Id;
        //ShowPhoto(filename);
    }
}

public static Stream ShowPhoto(string name)
{
    var server = MongoServer.Create("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    var database = server.GetDatabase("MyDB");
    var file = database.GridFS.FindOne(Query.EQ("filename",name));
    var stream = file.OpenRead())
    var bytes = new byte[stream.Length];
    stream.Read(bytes,0,(int)stream.Length);
    return stream;
}
```

You can now use the stream returned by ShowPhoto.

Comment: Am afraid I don't understand c#. I know about GridFs which am not going use as my images can easily be stored in regular document. Anyway I will figure out how to read from Mongodb later but now I just need to read from a string. My problem is that I don't know how to pass a binary string instead of a filename to imagemagick.

Comment: Either there has to be a way to pass a binary string to imagemagick or you may write this stream to a temp file and then use that file's name to pass to imagemagick..There's no compulsion about using GridFS..It's just good for images. But if your images are few and you have a dedicated collection in MongoDB storing only image binaries, then fine..use normal documents..Logic essentially remains the same. Instead of database.GridFS.FindOne, you write database.MyCollection.FindOne.

Comment: The temp thing is what am trying to avoid, see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295618/have-gd-get-image-from-binary-string . Bottom line what I am trying to do, is possible in PHP.

Comment: Now I am afraid I don't understand imagemagick at all but it seems the answer in the link you mentioned also creates a temp image variable and then destroys it.

Comment: Oops. I did notice that. I am going the temp route for now.