# Php, GD and greyscale in a foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, gd, grayscale

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Have GD get image from binary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295618/have-gd-get-image-from-binary-string)

I need to be able to change images into greyscale on the fly, within a foreach loop.

I'm basically taking set of image urls from the database and before I display them in  I need them to turn into greyscale, simply speaking.

Is it doable without actually creating a separate file as image source, which would process the file and output image headers?

Comment: yes I did, but majority of examples is just a simple createimagefromjpeg (or other ext) and imagejpeg (or other ext) and a use of image headers, which requires a php script in a separate file. I want to avoid adding a file like that to the server. Or, in other words, need to be sure this is the only way before I take further steps

Comment: @xception I don't agree. He wants to not create another php page.

Comment: @blue112 Look again at the question, he said his problem is that he has to create a file as image source, this avoids that by creating the image from the blob from the database passed as a string, that is unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @vault-boy In the following statement: `Is it doable without actually creating a separate file as image source, which would process the file and output image headers?` do you mean you create an image file as source for the gd object to turn them to grayscale or a php file as source for serving the image to the client?

Comment: @vault-boy you would be using too much system resources  ???? doing that

Comment: @xception
I have <img src="imagefile.jpg">
I need to display imagefile.jpg in a greyscale, without changing src to eg. src="processimage.php?image=imagefile.jpg"

Comment: @baba it's only on homepage, it's no more than 10-12 images and they're fairly small

Comment: @vault-boy you can generate them them put them in a folder .. only generate one that don't have the gray scale version ..... If you are ok .. i can come up with a code on that

Comment: @Baba I'm not in a position to modify image upload module in order to add such functionality. I can only work with whatever comes back from the database (image paths in this case)

Comment: @vault-boy yes you can still work with what comes from the database .. if you have path to the image

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to process image before displaying, and to not call php script as image source, neither save image as new, you can do that with base64 image source.

Something like :

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoABBANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

You can use the base64_encode on the image to get the base64 encoded data.

```
$out = base64_encode(imagepng($im));
echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.$out.'" />';
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: tried that but all I get is a bunch of messed up characters in the source

Answer (score 0):

If css3 is acceptable try this:

```
.grayscale {
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -kthml-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

add `class="grayscale"` to your img. This way you can still use the original images but they will be displayed in grayscale to the user. If you add

```
filter: gray;
```

to the above it will even work in IE6-9

demo using the class on an iframe: http://jsfiddle.net/8BDVn/

Comment: I've already played with css3. The above doesn't work on Firefox

Comment: for firefox look at http://demosthenes.info/blog/532/Convert-Images-To-Black-And-White-With-CSS - there's a svg filter there, you'll need to download that svg probably to your server