# What am I missing or doing wrong, trying to get image out of database using BLOB

Tags: php, html, image, mysqli

I am trying to get images out of the database using Blob, I know its not secure but it is for demo purposes. Below is the code I have at the moment.

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require './db/connect.php';
include './includes/header.php';
?>

<?php
    if($result = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM Production")){
            if($count = $result->num_rows){

                while($row = $result->fetch_object()){
                    ?>
            <table class="productioninfo" style="width: auto; height: auto; border: 5px black solid;">    
            <tr>
                <th>Image:</th>
                <td><img src="/phpmyadmin/production/<?php echo $row->ProductionId;?>.jpeg" </td>

                <th>Production Name:</th>
                <td><?php echo $row->ProductionName; ?></td>

                <th>Production Type:</th>
                <td><?php echo $row->ProductionType; ?></td></br>
            </tr>


                <?php
        }
        $result->free();
    }
}
echo $result; 

include './includes/footer.php';
```

Also I want to know how to do it the other way, by having the file path in the database and then displaying it on the web page.

Many Thanks for your help!

[image: table structure]

Comment: please share your production table structure.

Comment: Your code seems to assume that it it the path that is stored and not the image data. Check for example here if you have image data in the database: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295618/have-gd-get-image-from-binary-string

Comment: @harry look above I have edited it into my question :)

Comment: I'd first make sure your image retrieval script is working properly. Call `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/production/1.jpeg` (or use whatever ID you know exists) and check that a valid image is returned. I agree with @jeroen -- the way this URL is formed looks like a mistake, unless you've also reconfigured Apache. Finally, it's quite strange that you're adding your development files to the phpmyadmin folder; you should do your development in another folder. Show some of your image-display code. How are you storing the images in the database -- show the code you used to upload them.

Answer (score 0):

While saving an image to database, You have to encode it and then save to db. & while showing it in HTML you have to decode it.

eccoding :

```
$img_encoded = base64_encode('your image');
```

decode and show in HTML

```
<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.$img_encoded.'"/>
```

Comment: You can also google for creating bas64 image. Upload ur image they will give you encoded string, Store that string in ur database. Then fetch it and show in image with src as base64

Answer (score 0):

An arror in this line:

`<td><img src="/phpmyadmin/production/<?php echo $row->ProductionId;?>.jpeg"</td>`.

Try to close correctly the **img** tag :

`<td><img src="/phpmyadmin/production/<?php echo $row->ProductionId;?>.jpeg" /></td>`

Then be sure that the image was correctly encoded and decoded respectively when storing and retrieving.